C# .NET Core Unit Test data access layer method that use SQL Connection and SQL Command - could not mock this concrete class
The data access layer code has couple of method for fetch and update. please find sample that has one method. I need to write unit test. The challenge I face is I'm unable to mock SqlConnection and SqlCommand with isolation from database.
public class DataAccessLayer : IDataAccessLayer
{
    private readonly string _connectionString;
    private readonly ILogger<DataAccessLayer> _logger;
    private Settings _Settings { get; }

    TextInfo textInfo = new CultureInfo("en-US", false).TextInfo;

    public DataAccessLayer(string connectionString, ILogger<DataAccessLayer> logger, IOptions<Settings> emailAlertSettings)
    {
        _connectionString = connectionString;
        _logger = logger;
        _Settings = emailAlertSettings.Value;
    }

    public async Task<DataTable> ExecuteNonQueryWithResultAsync(string storedProcedureName, SqlParameter[] parameters = null)
    {
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
            {
                await connection.OpenAsync();

                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(storedProcedureName, connection))
                {
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    // Add input parameters, if any
                    if (parameters != null)
                    {
                        command.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);
                    }

                    // Execute the stored procedure
                    using (SqlDataReader reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync(CommandBehavior.SingleResult))
                    {
                        // Get schema information for the result set
                        dataTable.Load(reader);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex, "DataAccessLayer: Got exception when excecuting ExecuteNonQueryWithResultAsync method");
            // Handle SQL exceptions appropriately
            throw;  // Rethrow for further handling
        }

        return dataTable;
    }
}

This is the Xunit test code as shown below, but I'm getting error in m.OpenAsync() and m.ExecuteReaderAsync:

IDbConnection does not contain a definition for 'OpenAsync'


'IDbCommand' does not contain a definition for 'ExecuteReaderAsync'


No accessible extension method 'ExecuteReaderAsync' accepting a first argument of type 'IDbCommand'

Please advise how to build a valid unit test.
public class DataAccessLayerTests : DataAccessLayerFixture
{
    [Fact]
    public async Task ExecuteNonQueryWithResultAsync_ReturnsEmptyDataTable_Test()
    {
        // Arrange (Similar setup as previous test)
        var mockConnection = new Mock<IDbConnection>();
        var mockCommand = new Mock<IDbCommand>();
        var mockReader = new Mock<DbDataReader>();

        mockConnection.Setup(m => m.OpenAsync()).Returns(Task.CompletedTask);
        mockCommand.Setup(m => m.ExecuteReaderAsync(CommandBehavior.SingleResult))
                       .Returns(Task.FromResult(mockReader.Object));

        // Mock no data in the result set
        mockReader.Setup(r => r.HasRows).Returns(false);

        string storedProcedureName = "MyStoredProcedure";
        SqlParameter[] parameters = null; // No parameters in this example

        var dataAccessLayer = new DataAccessLayer(_connectionString, _mockLogger.Object, _mockOptions);

        // Act
        DataTable dataTable = await dataAccessLayer.ExecuteNonQueryWithResultAsync(storedProcedureName, parameters);

        // Assert
        Assert.NotNull(dataTable);
        Assert.Empty(dataTable.Columns); // No columns expected
        Assert.Empty(dataTable.Rows); // No rows expected
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task ExecuteNonQueryWithResultAsync_ReturnsDataTable_Test()
    {
        // Arrange
        var mockConnection = new Mock<IDbConnection>();
        var mockCommand = new Mock<IDbCommand>();
        var mockReader = new Mock<DbDataReader>();

        mockConnection.Setup(m => m.OpenAsync()).Returns(Task.CompletedTask);
        mockCommand.Setup(m => m.ExecuteReaderAsync(CommandBehavior.SingleResult))
                   .Returns(Task.FromResult(mockReader.Object));

        // Mock data for the result set (replace with your expected data)
        mockReader.Setup(r => r.HasRows).Returns(true);
        mockReader.Setup(r => r.Read()).Returns(true); // Simulate one row
        mockReader.Setup(r => r["ColumnName1"]).Returns("Value1"); // Replace with actual column names and values

        string storedProcedureName = "MyStoredProcedure";
        SqlParameter[] parameters = null; // No parameters in this example

        var dataAccessLayer = new MyDataAccessLayer("connectionString");

        // Act
        DataTable dataTable = await dataAccessLayer.ExecuteNonQueryWithResultAsync(storedProcedureName, parameters);

        // Assert
        Assert.NotNull(dataTable);
        Assert.NotEmpty(dataTable.Columns);
        Assert.Single(dataTable.Rows); // Expect one row

        // You can add further assertions to verify specific column values based on your mock setup
    }


I find that unit testing the data access layer doesn't make a lot of sense as it shouldn't contain any logic other than writing to and reading  from a DB. Instead I normally write a small set of integration tests using an in-memory DB (like Sqlite or H2).

Thank for the response. I too was thinking about that as alternative. Appreciate if you can provide sample code or link. SQL Server used in our environment and how to setup in memory db, etc

SQL Server can't run in-process like Sqlite can, if you rely on SQL Server specific SQL bits you'll need to look at something like testcontainers and then just build a connection string that points to that ephemeral database, shouldn't be too hard.

I got suggestion to move SQLConnection and SQL Command Creation to another class and inject that to DataAccessLayer so that those thing can be mocked. but I face challenge in adding dependency injection in program.cs since creation  DataAccessLayer use new  keyword
